# How to change website url path in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, seo

I have checked my google analytics and there (Behavior>>Site Content>>All Pages) URLs wrong showing how to solve this problem (i.e. /contact/www.example.com) this type URL format showing in google analytics.

This reason to not tracking any goal of my website can you please help me how to do.

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the SEO tag states, GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check in your filters, you probably have a badly configured Url rewrite filter.

Comment: Thank you for replying, 

I have checked my configured URL rewrite filter it is prefect nothing and the same filter applied to another website also but that website not affected.